# How can I validate the segment_ids argument of tf.unsorted_segments_max?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

In TensorFlow 1.12 you can use [tf.math.unsorted_segment_sum](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.12/api_docs/python/tf/math/unsorted_segment_sum) to compute the maximum along segments of a tensor.

One of the arguments:

> **segment_ids**: *A Tensor. Must be one of the following types: int32, int64. A tensor whose shape is a prefix of data.shape.END } out_arg {
>   name: "output" description: << END Has same shape as data, except for
>   the first segment_ids.rank dimensions, which are replaced with a
>   single dimension which has size num_segments.*

**Q1:** I don't understand what this means. I suppose `segment_ids` should be `[0,1,2,3,...]`, and serial number starts with 0.

Then I tried to verify my assumption by testing with different values for `segment_ids`:

```
print(sess.run(tf.unsorted_segment_max(tf.constant([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4]),
                                       tf.constant([2, 0, 1, 1, 0]), 3)))
#[0.4 0.3 0.1], correct
print(sess.run(tf.unsorted_segment_max(tf.constant([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4]),
                                       tf.constant([3, 0, 1, 1, 0]), 3)))
#[ 4.0000001e-01  3.0000001e-01 -3.4028235e+38], number 2 worked, but 3 didnt
print(sess.run(tf.unsorted_segment_max(tf.constant([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4]),
                                       tf.constant([3, 0, 1, 1, 0]), 4)))
#[ 4.0000001e-01  3.0000001e-01 -3.4028235e+38  1.0000000e-01], num_segments didnt help
print(sess.run(tf.unsorted_segment_sum(tf.constant([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4]),
                                       tf.constant([3, 0, 1, 1, 0]), 4)))
#[0.6 0.6 0.  0.1], while num_segments worked on sum.
```

From Ex3 and Ex4, I notice that `segment_ids` in `tf.unsorted_segment_max()` got  extra limitation other than `tf.unsorted_segment_sum()`, and I suppose it is consecutive from 0. Ex3 shall have `[0.4 0.3 0. 0.1]`

From Ex1 and Ex2, I notice that Ex1 result is right, while Ex2 shall have `[0.4 0.3 0.]` and there is no warning or error ocured if input `segment_ids` is invalid.

**Q2:** How can I check my `segment_ids` to see if it fits the requirements?

**Q3:** If my `segment_ids` doesn't fit the requirement, like `[3, 0, 1, 1, 0]`, what can I do to make `unsorted_segments_max work`?

Comment: I think there is a bug with number overflow in `tf.unsorted_segment_max` when id is not in `segment_ids`. `-3.4028235e+38` should be `0`.

Comment: @giser_yuyang My first example and the second one should have same result, if there is not extra limitation other than the `segment_inds` size. If there is, then it will be insecure to not check and just take it all.

Comment: First example and the second one should have different result. The results will only show up to `id=2` since you limit `num_segments=3`. In the first example,`0.4` represents `id=0` from `max(0.2,0.4)` ,`0.3` represents `id=1` 
 from `max(0.3,0.3)`,`0.1` represents `id=2` from `max(0.1)`. But there is no `id=2` in your second example, so it should return `0`.

Comment: you are right. My bad, I mean the segment 3 shall have `0.1`.  The consecutive shouldn't  make the result all wrong. That is why there is example 4. It shows that there is clearly  addon limitation on `segment_id` in `unsorted_segment_max` segment did not appears shall be `0.` So that is not a bug, the input `[3, 0, 1, 1, 0]` is invalid

Comment: I'm Sorry. There in no bug that I didn't notice the documentation with **If the maximum is empty for a given segment ID `i`, it outputs the smallest possible value for the specific numeric type**. Why shall the segment 3 have `0.1` in second example? You set `num_segments=3` will let it show to `id=2`. `0.1` is only available when you set `num_segments=4`, as in your third example.

Comment: I know, I set ex3 to see if it can get `0.1`.

Comment: @giser_yuyang I redit and add expected result to make it clear.  Feel free to post anything.

Comment: Are you want to replace `-3.4028235e+38` to `0`? It seems that `tf.unsorted_segment_max()` can't support it. Maybe you have to deal other meathods like `tf.where` after you get the results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193241/discussion-between-tina-liu-and-giser-yugang).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A1:** For the one-dimensional case the output tensor will have as many elements as specified by `num_segments`. Each element `i` will be the result of the operation (e.g. `max`, `sum`, ...) being applied to all elements in `data`, denoted by position `j`, for which `segment_ids[j] == i`. The `segment_ids` can be any numbers and don't necessarily need to start at `0`. Nevertheless the output will contain `num_segments` elements and if for any output element `i` no `segment_ids[j] == i` is found then a specific default value is used (this value is different for each of the operations). For higher dimensional tensors the first `x` dimensions of `data`, as specified by the rank of `segment_ids`, will be replaced by such a single dimension containing the various segments.

### Your examples

You didn't seem to run your examples on `tensorflow >= 1.12.0` because the second example should have raised an exception: `InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): segment_ids[0] = 3 is out of range [0, 3)`. The fact that it is ignored is probably the behavior in older versions (please check).

From the documentation of [`tf.math.unsorted_segment_max`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.12/api_docs/python/tf/math/unsorted_segment_max):

> If the maximum is empty for a given segment ID `i`, it outputs the smallest possible value for the specific numeric type, `output[i] = numeric_limits<T>::lowest()`.

1. You specify 3 segments and so the output has 3 elements. The first element, `i == 0`, corresponds to locations `j == [1, 4]` (as specified in `segment_ids`) and hence `data[j] == [0.2, 0.4]`. Taking the `max(data[j])` yields `0.4`. Similarly for the next segment, `i == 1`, we have `j == [2, 3]` and `data[j] = [0.3, 0.3] => max(data[j]) = 0.3`. For the last segment, `i == 2`, there is only a single element at position `j == 0` and hence the result is `0.1`.
2. Now you still specify 3 clusters and so the output will have 3 elements. The segment_id `3` seems to be ignored because it doesn't fit the number of segments (this should raise an error on the latest version of tensorflow though). Regarding the last element in the output, which corresponds to the segment `i == 2`, no corresponding `segment_id` is found and hence the result is *the smallest possible value for the specific numeric type*; this is what you observe: `-3.4028235e+38`.
3. Similar to 2) with the difference that now the segment_id `3` becomes effective; this corresponds to the last element in the output which is thus `0.1`. The second to last element, corresponding to segment_id 2 has still no matching ids, and is hence filled by the default value.
4. For [`tf.math.unsorted_segment_sum`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.12/api_docs/python/tf/math/unsorted_segment_sum) the default value for empty segments is different: *If the sum is empty for a given segment ID `i`, `output[i] = 0`.* Hence segment `0` is the sum of items `0.2 + 0.4 == 0.6`, for segment 1 it is `0.3 + 0.3 == 0.6`, for segment 2 no corresponding id can be found and thus it is `0` by default and for segment 3 there is only a single element `0.1`.

**A2:** The criteria for `segment_ids` are that it "prefixes" the shape of `data`, i.e. `segment_ids.shape == data.shape[:len(segment_ids.shape)]` and that `max(segment_ids) < num_segments` (on the latest version of tensorflow). The corresponding dimensions will then be reduced to a single one, containing as many elements as specified by `num_segments` while the values in `segments_ids` specify the corresponding segments in the output.

**A3:** In case the `segment_ids` argument doesn't meet the requirements an [`InvalidArgumentError`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/errors/InvalidArgumentError) will be raised. You'll have to fix the corresponding tensor in order to make the operation work.

Comment: I didn't get this error. but the `-3.4028235e+38` is the smallest number can answer my question. I shouldn't expected 0.

Comment: @TinaLiu What version of tensorflow do you use? The different `unsorted_segment_*` methods reduce the elements corresponding to each segment to a single number and since segments may be empty they need a sensible default that is compatible with the associated operator (i.e. not invalidating the result when combined with the first element of the segment). For `unsorted_segment_sum` the default is `0` because `0 + x == x` and hence for `unsorted_segment_prod` it is `1` (`1 * x == x`). Similarly for `unsorted_segment_{min,max}` the default is `numeric_limits<T>::{max,lowest}()`.

Comment: TF1.12. That's why the number is different! Brilliant. It is really nice to know things behind the code. THANK YOU :D